# Cannot push or fetch from remote repository in git

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-push, git-fetch

I was able to initialize my remote repository on GitHub. See message:

```
git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/sonicspark/Web-Developer-Course
  Push  URL: https://github.com/sonicspark/Web-Developer-Course
 HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    Staging tracked
    master  tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

For some reason I cannot push or fetch data from my remote repository using these commands:

`git fetch Web-Developer-Course`

`git push Web-Developer-Course master`

I get the following error message from both of the commmands:

```
fatal: 'Web-Developer-Course' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I already successfully published my public key to my GitHub account. Any help finding out why I cannot push or fetch to my remote repository would be helpful.

Comment: Hint: your remote is named `origin`, not `Web-Developer-Course`.

Comment: After using origin instead of Web-Developer-Course I was able to run the:

Comment: After using `origin` instead of `Web-Developer-Course` I was able to run the: `git fetch origin` command but it did not pull the file down from` Web-Developer-Course` repository, so GitBash told me to use the `git pul`l command and that worked. The `git push origin` command gives me this message: Everything up-to-date. When I check the Web-Developer-Course GitHub repository the info.txt file is not in the repository.

Comment: Add, commit, push.

Comment: Wonderful! Ran the following commands and everything processed, beautifully: `git add info.txt` `git commit``git push origin master`. Thank you @phd!